# How to validate signup form upon sign-in - Swagger/OpenAPI

Tags: forms, validation, yaml, swagger, openapi

I am brand new to Swagger/OpenAPI. However, this seems like a simple start.

I am trying to validate whether a username and password have been entered into the text fields when a user signs in.

I can't seem to get the responses (400, 200, etc) to work. I'm not really sure if I'm using this service properly.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Hello Swagger
  description: Validate user sign-in form has been properly filled
  version: 2.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      summary: validate form data
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: validates fields are filled
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        "201":
          description: User created.
        "405":
          description: Required fields usernme and password are not filled.
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    required:
      - username
      - password
    properties:
      username:
        description: Requires username
        type: string
      password:
        description: Requires password
        type: string
```

Ive been trying to make a POST request to a specific endpoint, which requires both username and password strings. Ultimately, I keep getting 404 errors and none of my responses will show.

Comment: How are you sending requests, using which tool? Also, what server do you need to send the requests to (e.g. `localhost` or `https://some.existing.server`)? I'm asking because your API definition does not specify the [`host`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/).

Comment: ahh yes, I copied what I posted into the swagger editor. I used node.js and I used `host: localhost:3000`. going to localhost:3000/users in my webpage would render a 405 error saying I was doing a GET when I needed to POST. So I went into terminal and made a POST request from there, which seemed to render a 200. This seems like it worked, however I couldn't break it. I tried empty strings in my curl and wrong names but it always gave a 200. Im so confused. Also it was supposed to give me a 201 response no?

Comment: `curl -X POST "localhost:3000/users" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"username\": \"hello\", \"password\": \"hiiiii\"}"` - what I put into terminal for my POST request